# "open -h" unable to find headers

Tags: xcode, bash, macos, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

Ever since I installed the Xcode 6 beta, i'm no longer able to see any headers when I type `open -h {header}`.  A typical interaction looks like:

```
$ open -h NSView
Unable to find header file matching NSView
$
```

I can find the headers, they're deep in the Xcode SDK bundles, which is fine, but `open -h` doesn't seem to be aware of this location.  Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you set the Xcode 6 Location preferences to point into Xcode 6?

Comment: I'm not sure which location preferences would be appropriate.

Comment: I guess I was thinking of switching the Command Line Tools so that xcrun etc. points into the beta. But this still might not work. `open -h` was lovely but it has not worked for me (for iOS) in quite a long time, so if it is now broken for you as well, the best you can do is file a bug (and please do).

Answer (score 0):

The `open -h ...` command looks in `/System/Libraries/Frameworks/{FrameworkName.Framework}/Headers` directory for any header files. Many Xcode-related framework header files (Foundation, CoreData, AppKit, etc.) somehow were removed after I installed the latest Xcode beta.

Manually running the latest **Command Line Tools for Xcode** installer restored the missing framework headers for me.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... All you do is:

```
xcrun open -h $symbol
```

`xcrun` makes `open` work somehow